# \toprule is not spanning the width of the table

Tags: tabularx, multirow, ieeetran, booktabs, pdflscape

I am trying to create a landscape table that spans the vertical length of a page. The following is what I get:

[image]

The table almost looks good, except for the following:

1. The `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` are not spanning the width of the table.
2. After using `\cmidrule` instead of `\crule`, the vertical spaces between rows increased and the column title that spans multiple rows looks bad.
3. Following up on 2, is there a better way to make a long column title span multiple rows?

Finally, where can I find the description of the line: `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{14}{C}c@{}}`

Here is the code that generates this table:

```
    \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" type

    \begin{document}

    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}
    \caption{Summary of Columns}
    \label{tab:OWCStandards}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*{14}{C}c@{}}
    \toprule
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{First}}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Second}}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Third}}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Fourth}}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Fifth}}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Sixth}}}
    & \multicolumn{8}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Multi-Column Here}}} \tabularnewline
    \cmidrule[0.05em]{7-14}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Column}}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Column}}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Columns}}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
    & \multicolumn{6}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Sub-column 1}}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Sub-column 2}}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Sub-column 3}}} \tabularnewline
    \cmidrule{7-12}
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Here}}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Here}}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Col 1-1}}  
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Col 1-2}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Col 1-3}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Col 1-4}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Col 1-5}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Col 1-6}} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Here}}} \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    \midrule
    %\midrule

    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    \end{landscape}

    \end{document}
```

---

### EDIT

I used `\linewidth` and added a sample line of data. This is what I got:

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" type
% \setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}

\begin{document}



\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\caption{Summary of Columns}
\label{tab:OWCStandards}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}*{14}{C}c@{}}
\toprule
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{First}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Second}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Third}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Fourth}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Fifth}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Sixth}}}
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Multi-Column Here}}} \tabularnewline
\cmidrule[0.05em]{7-14}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Column}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Column}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Columns}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Sub-column 1}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Sub-column 2}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Sub-column 3}}} \tabularnewline
\cmidrule{7-12}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Here}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Here}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Col 1-1}}  
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Col 1-2}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Col 1-3}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Col 1-4}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Col 1-5}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Col 1-6}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{1}{*}{\textbf{Here}}} \tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{ c }{\multirow{2}{*}{Smart City}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c }{\multirow{2}{*}{2018}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c }{\multirow{2}{*}{\cite{}}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c }{\multirow{1}{*}{Smart}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c }{\multirow{2}{*}{Implementation}}        
& \multicolumn{1}{c }{\multirow{2}{*}{Broadcast}}                      
& \multicolumn{1}{c }{\multirow{2}{*}{LED}}                         
& \multicolumn{1}{c }{\multirow{2}{*}{PD}}                        
& \multicolumn{1}{c }{\multirow{2}{*}{N/A}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c }{\multirow{2}{*}{1.5 m}}                          
& \multicolumn{1}{c }{\multirow{2}{*}{IEEE 802.11OCB}}                
& \multicolumn{1}{c }{\multirow{2}{*}{N/A}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c }{\multirow{2}{*}{N/A}} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c }{\multirow{2}{*}{N/A}} \tabularnewline
\multicolumn{1}{ c }{}& \multicolumn{1}{c }{}
& \multicolumn{1}{c }{} &\multicolumn{1}{c }{Vehicle}
&\multicolumn{1}{c }{} & \multicolumn{1}{c }{}
& \multicolumn{1}{c }{}& \multicolumn{1}{c }{}
& \multicolumn{1}{c }{} & \multicolumn{1}{c }{}
& \multicolumn{1}{c }{} & \multicolumn{1}{c }{} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c }{} & \multicolumn{1}{c }{}
& \multicolumn{1}{c }{} \tabularnewline

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: On a landscape page, use `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth` if you want a `tabularx` to be as wide as the textblock.

Comment: What will the actual contents of your table look like? Will there be text, numbers, single words...? Depending on the contents of the table, `tabularx` might not be the best choice. Also, you defined a total of 15 columns but only seem to use 14 of them.

Comment: It will be a mix of numbers and text. Do you think once I place the actual contents, the widths will adjust?

Comment: Which width should adjust? You specified a table with 14 columns of equal width and a fifteenth column that is as wide as its widest content. Which columns should contain numbers ans how long is the text?

Comment: Regarding your recent edit: I would not use `tabularx` for this kind of table. A regular `tabular` with `l` or `c` type columns should be fine.

Comment: The white space at the right of your table is due to the 15th column you added. (The `c` in `{@{}*{14}{C}c@{}}`.

Comment: What are all those `\multirow{1} ` and `\multicolumn{1}{c}` for?

Comment: @leandriis I used tabular and that fixed the first problem.

Comment: @Bernard Do you mean those blank ones or the ones that are actually filed? The blanks are just for place holding. I am trying to build that multilevel table header. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: you have `\multicolumn` in _every_ cell that makes no sense and breaks tabularx, why are they there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the reason why the `tabularx` environment doesn't take up the full assigned width: Even though you've specified 14 centered versions of the `X` column type, LaTeX actually never gets to act on them because *every single cell* is wrapped in a `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` "wrapper"; hence, all that LaTeX ever sees is the `c` column type, not the `X` column type.

Anyway, it's both possible and desirable to get rid of all those wrappers -- and to ditch the `\multirow` wrappers as well. (The instruction `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` arranges for vertical centering of cell contents automatically.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx,booktabs,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{% handy utility macro
    \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\Centering}p{\hsize}@{}}
    \bfseries #1 \end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt
\caption{Summary of Columns}
\label{tab:OWCStandards}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} *{14}{C} @{}}
\toprule
  \mytab{First Column Here}
& \mytab{Second}
& \mytab{Third}
& \mytab{Fourth Column}
& \mytab{Fifth Column Here}
& \mytab{Sixth}
& \multicolumn{8}{c@{}}{\textbf{Multi-Column Here}}\\
\cmidrule(l){7-14}
& & & & &  
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Sub-column 1}}
& \mytab{Sub-column 2}
& \mytab{Sub-column 3 Here} 
\\
\cmidrule(lr){7-12}
& & & & & 
& \textbf{Col 1-1} & \textbf{Col 1-2} & \textbf{Col 1-3} 
& \textbf{Col 1-4} & \textbf{Col 1-5} & \textbf{Col 1-6}
\\
\midrule
  Smart City
& 2018
& \cite{}
& Smart Vehicle
& Implementation
& Broadcast
& LED                        
& PD                        
& N/A
& 1.5 m                          
& IEEE 802.11OCB                
& N/A
& N/A
& N/A 
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A code with the `sidewaystable` environment, with all those `\multicolumn{1}{c}` removed, and a systematic use of `\multirow{n}{=}{contents}` since you're using fixed width columns, which enables use  `\\` inside them to get a newline in the cell:

```
 \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" type
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage{graphicx, rotating}
 \usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\caption{Summary of Columns}
\label{tab:OWCStandards}
\begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{@{}*{14}{C}@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{6}{c}{}
& \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{Multi-Column Here}} \tabularnewline
\cmidrule[0.05em]{7-14}
\multirow{-2}{=}{\bfseries\centering First\\ Column\\ Here}
& {\bfseries\centering Second }
&{\bfseries\centering Third}
& \multirow{-1.5}{=}{\bfseries \centering Fourth\\ Column}
& \multirow{-2}{=}{\bfseries\centering Fifth\\ Column \\ Here}
&{\bfseries\centering Sixth}
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Subcolumn 1}}
& \multirow{2}{=}{\small\bfseries\centering Subcolumn 2}
&\multirow{2}{=}{\small\bfseries\centering Subcolumn 3 Here} \tabularnewline%
\cmidrule{7-12}
\multicolumn{6}{c}{}
& \textbf{Col 1-1}
& \textbf{Col 1-2}
& \textbf{Col 1-3}
& \textbf{Col 1-4}
& \textbf{Col 1-5}
& \textbf{Col 1-6}
&
 \tabularnewline
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{ c }{Smart City}
& 2018 
& \cite{}
& Smart Vehicle
& Implemen\-tation
& Broadcast
& LED  & PD & N/A & 1.5 m 
& IEEE 802.11OCB 
& N/A & N/A & N/A
 \tabularnewline
    \midrule
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]